# x509 certificate signed by unknown authority on Docker 1.3.2 rhel 7 host

Tags: docker

I setup docker (1.3.2) on a rhel 7 host in AWS to run a registry and have nginx configured to proxy traffic to that container. On another rhel 7 host I have copied the ca.crt when I run

```
$ curl --cacert /tmp/ca.crt https://user:test@repo.test
```

I am able to see the registry I get the below response.

```
"\"docker-registry server\""
```

However when I try to run

```
$ docker login repo.test:443
```

and put in the username password and email I get the following error.

```
2015/01/14 16:59:48 Error response from daemon: Server Error: Post https://repo.test/v1/users/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

I'm running the docker daemon with `--insecure-registry repo.test:443`

I've tried to import the ca.crt by placing the cert in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and running

```
$ update-ca-trust enable
$ update-ca-trust extract
```

but I'm still getting the error.

It would be much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: ok going to solve my own problem I created a cert using the below tool on my mac https://github.com/deckarep/EasyCert I then added the cert to /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt and I can now run docker login.  Seems like its an issue in go and using this tool creates the cert properly. hope this helps others that might be having the same issue.